# Pandas: return NaN rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am trying to return a df that contains all of the `NaN` values for `column == years_exp` so that I can identify the corresponding `id.thomas` (basically I'm debugging some data that I parsed by hand).  I also need to return a df with all `min` values. This is what I have tried so far:

```
rr.head(5)

    years   id.thomas   years_exp
55  2005          2     17
56  2006          2     18
57  2007          2     19
58  2008          2     20
59  2009          2     21

c = rr
c = c[c.years_exp == 'NaN']
```

Error:

> TypeError: invalid type comparison

I'm using syntax that I copied from a youtube video on Pandas. Does anyone have an idea about the error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for checking `NaN` values:

```
print (rr[rr.years_exp.isnull()])
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

> **Warning**
>
> One has to be mindful that in python (and numpy), the nan's don’t compare equal, but None's do. Note that Pandas/numpy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan.

```
In [11]: None == None
Out[11]: True

In [12]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[12]: False
```

> So as compared to above, a scalar equality comparison versus a None/np.nan doesn’t provide useful information.

```
In [13]: df2['one'] == np.nan
Out[13]: 
a    False
b    False
c    False
d    False
e    False
f    False
g    False
h    False
Name: one, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @ jezrael: Thank you for the suggestion. One problem is that I have 50K+ rows and only want to return the rows with NaN. I applied you code above `print (c[c.years_exp.isnull()])` it returns `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [years, id.thomas, years_exp]
Index: []`

Comment: Yes, it ir right, because in `c` is no `NaN` value. I think you need `print (rr[rr.years_exp.isnull()])`

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You can try with

```
c = c.loc[c.years_exp == 'NaN']
```

or

```
c = c.loc[c.years_exp == None]
```

or

```
c = c.loc[c.years_exp.isnull()]
```